# Incremental backups with 7-zip

Tags: backup, archiving, 7-zip, incremental-backup

I am trying to set up an incremental backup with 7-zip after finding zip might not suit my needs fully/easily. My data is located in /media/Data/Work. For some reason it is not liking my code. I've tried the following 2 scripts:

`7za u /media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/workfullbkup.7z /media/Data/Work -ms=off -mx=1 -u- -up0q3r2x2y2z0w2 /media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/diff1.7z`

Results in `7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=C,Utf16=off,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)
Everything is Ok`

and:

`7za u /media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/workfullbkup.7z /media/Data/Work -ms=off -mx=1 -u- -up0q3r2x2y2z0w2!/media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/diff1.7z`

Results in `bash: !/media/SAMSUNG/backups/work/diff1.7z: event not found`

The archive workfullbkup.7z is my existing full backup. diff1.7z does not exist. Let me know your thoughts or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: are you just missing a space between arguments?